# ASP.NET Core prerender error ('deps' required)

Tags: angular, single-page-application, asp.net-core-2.0

I get the following error in ASP.NET Core 2.0 app when using aspnet-prerendering:

```
NodeInvocationException: StaticInjectorError[{provide:PlatformLocation, useClass:ServerPlatformLocation}]: 'deps' required
Error: StaticInjectorError[{provide:PlatformLocation, useClass:ServerPlatformLocation}]: 'deps' required
```

In my boot.server.ts I have

```
import { platformDynamicServer, PlatformState, INITIAL_CONFIG } from '@angular/platform-server';
```

**package.json**

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/forms": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/http": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "4.2.5",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.5.0",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
    "angular2-router-loader": "0.3.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
...
    "typescript": "2.4.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "2.5.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
...
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ngx-cookie": "^2.0.1"
  }
```

Could anybody help me how to fix this error? Should I add import or provide entry somewhere maybe? Where? 
Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To let others know, who are interested, and to say thanks for the help, here I publish the way I managed to overcome this problem.

svoychik shared with me with a starter project with ngx-cookie included out of the box. [Here is the repo on github](https://github.com/svoychik/dotNetCoreNgxCookieExample).

With this project, serving as a starting point, I have the service working now, but I cannot tell you what was the reason of not being able to implement it in the existing project in VS2017 (generated from the stock new project ASP.NET web site template).

As a reference, here is our conversation on [ngx-cookie github](https://github.com/salemdar/ngx-cookie/issues/43).

Good luck.